# Sql database to Salesforce data migration

Tags: integration

Our SQL database doesn't support any web services at this moment. So to one time load the data from SQL --> Salesforce org. What are the ways that we can approach?

I have these things in mind. Correct me if I am wrong.

1) Converting .bak file to .csv
2) Using Jitterbit for Integration purposes. As we have datapoints like SAP , MS dynamc in future to load data into salesforce

Any insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a one time migration, you could simply export all your data as a .csv file and then use the Data Loader or Import Wizard to import it into Salesforce. It depends on the amount of records though. I haven't had any issues importing up to a million records with the Data Loader, however I would recommend using the Bulk API and doing it on a fast machine (to spare you some pain, handling huge .csv files can be troublesome)

There are a lot of ETL tools that do SQL => Salesforce. To name a few: dataloader.io, Jitterbit, Informatica Cloud, Talend, Skyvia

Comment: Can we convert .bak file into .csv ? If this is possible then it would be the best possible approach. Please clear me on this?

Comment: What format is your .bak file? Usually .bak is a backup/copy of a file. You can export a .csv with all of your data by running a SQL query and exporting the result directly into a .csv file (once again, might not be feasible if you have lots of data/tables)

Answer (score 1):

You can create CSV(comma delimited) file from your SQL database and use Data loader to upload this to Salesforce. But the API access is not available for Professional edition and there is no support other than a help file.
To see the Data Loader’s documentation, you can go here -
https://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_data_loader.pdf

You can also use ETL tools like Informatica, DBSync, Jitter bit for the migration and also the good part with these tools is that you can use these on a regular basis without much manual work after initial configuration. Sync can be set on schedulers.

Answer (score -1):

You can use informatica cloud. 
It have a salesforce connector and you can synchronize easily your database(Oracle, Mysql etc...) into your salesforce organization.
Setting up a SFDC Connection:
https://community.informatica.com/docs/DOC-1633
Getting Started with Informatica Cloud:
http://www.youtube.com/embed/oS-ZALsE2II